# Specific zoom on doubleclick on pin marker

Tags: google-maps, google-api, zooming

Is it possible to zoom to some specific level after doubleclicking on the pin marker?
the point is to get quickly to the streets-level zoom 
I need to use it [here](http://ejot3.stan.sk/?page_id=103)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sample and adapt it as you want:
[Simple click event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple)

Just change `'click'` with `'dblclick'` to get it working with a double-click:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```